# Ramanujan's congruence.

Tags: number-theory, integer-partitions

There are the following formula in this link(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan%27s_congruences).

> $$\sum_{k=0}^{ \infty } p(5k+4)q^k = 5 \frac{(q^5)_{\infty}^{5}}{(q)_{\infty}^{6}}.$$
>
> $$\sum_{k=0}^{ \infty } p(7k+5)q^k = 7 \frac{(q^7)_{\infty}^{3}}{(q)_{\infty}^{4}} + 49q \frac{(q^7)_{\infty}^{7}}{(q)_{\infty}^{8}}.$$

Srinivasa Ramanujan discovered the following congruences.

> $$ p(11k+6) = 0　mod.11.$$

Do you know the formla of $\sum_{k=0}^{ \infty } p(11k+6)q^k $?

That is

> $$\sum_{k=0}^{ \infty } p(11k+6)q^k = ???.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, a formula for the series $\sum_{k=0}^{ \infty } p(11k+6)q^k $, written as $\sum_{n=1}^{ \infty } p(11n-5)q^n$, can be found in the paper [Ramanujan's unpublished manuscript on the partition and tau functions with proofs and commentary](http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~slc/s/s42berndt.pdf) by Bruce C. Berndt and Ken Ono, on page $39$, formula $(18.7)$:

$$
\sum_{n=1}^{ \infty } p(11n-5)q^n(q_{11};q_{11})_{\infty}=11\sigma_7(n)q^n+121J,
$$
which can be rewritten as you want, I suppose.

Comment: In the case of 5 and 7, there are the formula in the paper(Those are (4.7) and (8.3)). Are there the formula in the case of not 121 but 11?

Comment: Berndt and Ono would have noted further nice formulas of this type, I suppose. So perhaps it is more complicated.